# Best way to manage gem whenever for sending emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, whenever

In my application there are posts which are going to expire in certain time of a day.

After the expiration the customer needs to notify through emails.

I have used Rails cron `whenever` for in each 1 minute and it makes expire the post at the specified time and sends the email to customers.

**Schedule.rb**

```
every 1.minutes do
  rake "ad_has_expired_task"
end
```

Will be this a better way?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I think that's fine.  Another option would be to use `delayed_job` or `sidekiq` to add a scheduled email on the time of expiration.

Answer (score 3):

For small app, this way is good, but for a bigger app, that may keep cpu busy.

Here is a solution from my site.

```
gem sidekiq
gem whenever
```

in scheduler.rb

```
every 1.day do
  rake "scan_expired_task"
end
```

in rake taks scan_expired_task.rake

```
if post.will_expire_today
   MyMailerWoker.perform_async(related_user_ids, post.expired_at-Time.now)
end
```

Then you write your mailer program in your MyMailerWoker

The codes above can't be executed directly, you need to customize it by your business.

Hope it helps.

reference:

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Getting-Started